# Disable emojicons introduced with WP 4.2

Tags: filters, tinymce, icon, emoji

So WP 4.2 introduced emojis (smileys) that basically adds JS and other junk all over your pages. Something some people may find shocking. How does one completely erase all instances of this?

Comment: I was so shocked I almost collapsed in my chair when I read the announcement

Comment: o_O ... 9_9 ... >:-[(](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

We will hook into `init` and remove actions as followed:

```
function disable_wp_emojicons() {

  // all actions related to emojis
  remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
  remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
  remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
  remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
  remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );

  // filter to remove TinyMCE emojis
  add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_emojicons' );
```

We will need the following filter function to disable TinyMCE emojicons:

```
function disable_emojicons_tinymce( $plugins ) {
  if ( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
    return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
  } else {
    return array();
  }
}
```

Now we breathe and pretend this feature was never added to core... particularly while tons of *resolved* bugs are [yet](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) to be implemented.

This is available as a plugin, [Disable Emojis](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emojis/).

Alternatively, you can replace the smilies with the original versions from previous versions of WordPress using [Classic Smilies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-smilies/).

## Update

We can also remove the DNS prefetch by returning false on filter `emoji_svg_url` (thanks @yobddigi):

```
add_filter( 'emoji_svg_url', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why they didn't just allow people to enable / disable this via `Settings -> Writing` but it's definitely annoying. +1

Comment: Look forward to your "Disable emojicons" plugin in the repo or github ;-)

Comment: And remember to include a link in your answer where we can download the plugin ;-)

Comment: there's a couple of them already ( which this is a copy )
https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-smilies/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emojis/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't believe this is part of core, at least not with an "opt-in" or a way to disable it ~_~

Comment: And its shocking to see that they add 114 lines worth scripts and styles in the header that are not even minified. Thanks for the plugin...

Comment: maybe consider adding this one as well: `add_filter( 'emoji_svg_url', '__return_false' );` this removes the dns prefetch

Comment: @yobddigi Very nice, I have updated it accordingly!

Comment: WP is hitting us hard - since 4.3 "the option to disable graphic smileys was removed from new installs" and no "smileys" are *not* "emojis" ... You now have to a) `add_filter( 'option_use_smilies', function(){ return false; } );` or b) use this plugin (which does EXACTLY the same)  : https://wordpress.org/plugins/keep-emoticons-as-text/ I really do wonder who went and told him/herself "Yea, lets just alter user's content through PHP, no questions asked... " ... -_-

Answer (score 29):

Better solution if you want to disable this: use a plugin.

Same code as from Christine's comments:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emojis/

Same code that also fixes the smilies to be the older ones:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-smilies/

Source: Me, since I wrote that code in the first place.
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/1142480/classic-smilies

Comment: Nice! Although I came across the functions via a github entry. I've updated my answer with these plugin links. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you probably did. I put it on github too for a twitter user: https://gist.github.com/Otto42/b79ff5428993fcff45bb

Answer (score 15):

This is the simple way to remove emoji. Add bellow code to your `function.php`

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

Comment: This was already covered in my question above.

Comment: Thanks this removes the code nicely - oddly my pages take 2 to 3 seconds longer to load with this in my functions.php than without it.

Comment: This should run via `init`. See my [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185578/24875).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent Wordpress from automatically converting your old school ASCII smilies to Unicode emojis (like `;-)` to ) in your posts altogether, you might want to `remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_smilies')`

(Not 100% sure this is what the question's about, but this solved my problem and I hope it might be handy for someone.)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried some codes above but the only codes works on my end is this one.

Don't forget to back-up your functions.php before implementing these codes.

```
// REMOVE WP EMOJI
remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');

remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

Comment: Did you properly test the code in my answer?

Comment: yes I've tried it many times, site is on cloudflare-nginx server

Comment: Just double checked my code and it is working. When you add the code into your functions.php file, try setting a higher priority, like this: `add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_emojicons', 3 );`

Answer (score -1):

Good news, I added a feature request:

***Introduce a new option to WordPress WP_EMOICONS***
in here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38252

and apparently this has been marked as duplicate
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32102
so we may expect something like

```
define( 'WP_EMOICONS', false );
```

in the future WordPress releases.

Comment: It looks like ticket [#32102](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32102) is closed with *wontfix*.  +1 for trying and beeing optimistic ;-)

Comment: ps: as far as I understand it, your ticket #38252 was closed because it was a duplicate to ticket #32102, that was previously closed as a wontfix. So it looks like plugins will have to sort this out, for days to come ;-) Hence voting it up for you being so optimistic ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Since WordPress emoji are served from s.w.org and they are not compressed, this impacts the SVG loading time depending on how many emoji you are using, and can even throw warnings on Google’s PageSpeed Insights tool.

To fix this issue, you can serve the emoji directly from your WordPress site itself and not by making external calls through js.

This can be achieved by installing the plugin [Compressed Emoji](https://wordpress.org/plugins/compressed-emoji/) which is available for free in the WordPress.org plugin repository.

When the plugin is activated, the compression offers savings in the range of 3kb ~ 1.3kb (roughly %60) per emoji.

Source: [WPTavern](https://wptavern.com/new-wordpress-plugin-serves-pre-compressed-emoji)