# Emojicons introduced with WP 4.2 code not inline

Tags: emoji

This has probably been asked already but I can't find the answer. I don't want to disable emojis in my blog, just don't want that code to be inline in the blog's header (I reserve judgement on the way this was implemented).

What would be the way to remove it from my header and have the CSS and JS code in my theme's JS and CSS files instead as it should be?

Comment: Did you look at this [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185577/disable-emojicons-introduced-with-wp-4-2) and it's answers?

Comment: @birgire yes, I did. But they mention how to remove the code, not how to add it back again in a way better than injecting it inline into your html.